# How to control the scroll bar with QListWidget

Tags: qt

I am clearing and re populating a QListWidget based on a timer. Every time that happens, the list widget is scrolling back to the top. Can I find out the scroll position of the list and set it back again after adding the items?

Answer (score 6):

`QListWidget` is also a `QAbstractScrollArea`. It has a horizontal scrollbar and a vertical scrollbar, which you can obtain them using `QAbstractScrollArea::horizontalScrollBar()` and `QAbstractSrollArea::verticalScrollBar()`. Both return a `QScrollBar`.

To set the value of scroll bar manually, you can:

```
QScrollBar *vb = listWidget->verticalScrollBar();
int oldValue = vb->value();
//doSomething()
vb->setValue(oldValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and every time I changed the list item's properties or use "takeItem", the scrollbar jumped to a certain position near the top. It was solved after I removed "setLayoutMode" and "setBatchSize" to my QList? If these two methods are used in your code, take a try to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I find out the scroll position of the list and set it back again after adding the items?

It is possible by using [currentRow property](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentRow-prop) to get/set current row. It is best to subscribe to the [currentRowChanged signal](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentRowChanged).

Comment: Use [connect](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) to connect signals. If you are very new, start with [qt tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/tutorials.html). (sorry don't have access to compiler and qt library on pc I am currently using)

Comment: So do i need to create a scroll bar variable.. Till now all the settings for the scrollbar are by default settings..

Comment: [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_QListWidget_and_QListWidgetItem) you got an example how to create QListWidget